# Can I manually focus the camera on my Android phone?

Tags: camera

Is there any way to manually focus the camera on my Android phone?

I know that you can tap on where to focus, but that's just assisted auto focus. What I want is to be able to manually adjust the focus.

Comment: Change the focal depth?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do it or an app that would do it.  There were a couple out there that claimed to have manual focus but basically just did what you described as "assisted auto focus."

I found this thread at XDA where some people have been looking through the code to find a way to add the manual focus.  From what they found it appears that it is possible but someone has to code it.  Its worth keeping an eye on it: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=630989

Answer (score 8):

The new API for full control of the camera on android had been added to android version 5. Google added these features like iso ,manual focus and etc in android lollipop. I personally think to use this new API the camera hardware must support this features, However I didn't find any reference to claim this, but it makes sense to me that a hardware must be able to do such stuff.

you can use [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.vipek.camera2_compatibility_test) app to check Manual Camera Compatibility.

Comment: Is there a list of hardware that supports Manual Camera Compatibility API?

Answer (score 6):

There is a free android app that allows you to manually adjust focus (and more camera technical stuff for photographers) 
Its called open camera and can be found on playstore. 
(the one by mark harman) 
NOTE: it will only work if your device supports it. (aka if possible)

To get straight to using manual focous: 
install, open settings, near bottom of page turn "use camera2 API" on, then in camera mode (ready to take picture) click the "..." on the right side pannel, on the second row down of icons click the "m" (just above the "photo mode" words) (make sure your scolled to top, you can scroll down in that menu) 
It will then popup 'focus manual' and on the left side there is a big slider (above the zoom slider), you can drag that to manually focus your camera.

- someone who has had this app for a while. 
  Your welcome.

Comment: Open settings in open camera or the phone?

Comment: Thank you! The secret is in finding and using Camera2 API.

Answer (score 1):

My Hauwei Mate 9 has manual focus, ISO, and shutter speed options. I use it frequently for sunsets and stage lighting.

Answer (score 0):

Only 8 years later, the Moment Pro Photo app can now do this. May not be available for every phone, but it works as advertised on mine, specifically the manual focus.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shopmoment.momentprocamera

Comment: The linked app does no longer exists on Play Store.

Comment: @Robert Thanks, it looks like Moment stopped development on Android over a year ago... They have some alternatives recommended, but I haven't used any of them personally so not sure if any support manual focus: https://9to5google.com/2020/02/28/moment-pro-camera-app-android-support/ (As well there is another answer that is more recent than mine that looks like it references a good app, too, maybe?)